# The contraction of a given redex yields a unique result

Tags: lambda-calculus

I want to prove that if
$$(\lambda x. P)Q=(\lambda y. M)N$$ then $$P[x:=Q]= M[y:=N]$$
which means that the contraction of a given redex yields a unique result (so we don't have beta equivalence,  but alpha equivalence).

I would go for a proof by contradiction but I think it should be prooved by a variation of structural induction, as it seems quite a hasty conclusion that an occurence of x (or y) hasn't been substituted and that's why contractum's differ.

Though I have neither seen any variation of induction used somewhere, nor I can use it without proof.

So could anyone help?

I am studying from "Lectures on the Curry"-Howard isomorphism-Sorensen, Urzyczyn (2006)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. If $(\lambda x.P)Q = (\lambda y. M)N$ ($=$ is always in the sense of $\alpha$-equivalence here), then $\lambda x.P = \lambda y.M$ and $Q = N$, from that it follows that $P[x:=Q] = M[y:=N]$ because substitution is compatible with $\alpha$-equivalence..

Comment: Ohh... it was that simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Transferring here the answer in the comments so that the question won't be left in the unanswered posts forever.*

I'm not sure to understand your question. If $(.)=(.)$ (= is always in the sense of $$-equivalence here), then $.=.$ and $=$, from that it follows that $[:=]=[:=]$ because substitution is compatible with $$-equivalence..